# Why are ZIP archives created with PharData not compressed?

Tags: php, zip

I've tried to use `PharData` as it seemed to provide a nice way to create either ZIP or tar archives. Unfortunately it seems, that ZIP archives created this way have no compression at all:

```
/tmp# ls -lah
total 2.3M
drwxrwxrwt  5 root     root 4.0K Sep 16 14:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 82 root     root 4.0K Sep 16 14:54 ..
-rw-------  1 www-data 1000 2.3M Sep  2 16:46 test.csv
/tmp# php -a
Interactive shell

php > $a = new PharData('/tmp/test.zip', null, null, Phar::ZIP);
php > $a->addFile('/tmp/test.csv');
php > exit
/tmp# ls -lah
total 4.6M
drwxrwxrwt  5 root     root 4.0K Sep 16 14:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 82 root     root 4.0K Sep 16 14:54 ..
-rw-------  1 www-data 1000 2.3M Sep  2 16:46 test.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root 2.3M Sep 16 14:56 test.zip
```

`test.csv` has highly compressable CSV data. The compressed file should have about 500KB.

So what is the problem here?

Comment: If you want to create zip files, use ZipArchive.... that's the standard tool for doing so

Comment: But in answer to your question, use the methods `compress()` or `compressFiles()`

Comment: I know, that I could use `ZipArchive`. But that is not the question here.

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok, `compressFiles()` was the missing piece. `compress()` would throw an error here as it only works for Phar::TAR files. Thanks!

Comment: Still don't get it, there are still two files created, once for the constructor of PharData() and once for compress() (while I still don't get the difference between compress() and compressFiles())